# What is the definition of pt_spacing on Point File Information tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, lidar, 3d-analyst

I can't find any definition for the outputs of Point File Information tool (3D analyst), specifically the pt_spacing field.

Is this the average distance between points, or the average number of points per square foot?

Answer (score 1):

It is the average distance between points. See [here](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/lidar-analysis-forestry-10.pdf) on page 6, 3<sup>rd</sup> bullet.

> Average point spacing

At page 07, also  3<sup>rd</sup> bullet the document clarifies:

> The average point spacing as indicated by the statistics from the Pt_Spacing column. In this example, the average point spacing tends to be approximately 0.6 meter. The lidar dataset used in this paper was captured at a sampling density of two returns per square meter; thus, 0.6 meter gives a good approximation to the ordered capture rate.

Consider the following relationship between point spacing and point density:

[image]

I performed a test with a .las file with a known point density of 0.38 pt/ft² (see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342900/how-to-extract-descriptive-information-from-a-lidar-cloud-las-files/15347264#15347264)). The expected point spacing result would be approximately 1.62 ft.

In ArcMap 10.1 the result with the Point File Information tool was 1.63 ft.

[image]