# Using lastile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, tiles, lidar, las, lastools

I want to tile one large las tile into a few minor. But I just can't get it done.

My original las file have around 30 million points and I want to get 6 smaller las files with 5 million points in each.

What is that I don't know what exactly to put into "tile size" line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the 30 million points in the LiDAR cloud has a point density equal 10 points per square meter (m²), and therefore, the area of interest is of size 3 million m².
<sub>Here are some references to help you finding the point density: [1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85418/what-is-the-definition-of-pt-spacing-on-point-file-information-tool/85654#85654), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342900/how-to-extract-descriptive-information-from-a-lidar-cloud-las-files/15347264#15347264), [3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107677/lidar-data-density-returns-per-square-meter/107707#107707).</sub>

Now, for the sake of simplification let's assume the area of interest has a squared shape. This is because the [`lastile`](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/lastile_README.txt) tool uses a square tiling approach (the reasons for this are provided in the link above).

Then, if you want the original las file to be splitted in 6 smaller ones, each tile will have area equal to 3 million m² / 6 = 500 thousand m².

That means the dimensions of each tile are approximate 707 m x 707 m (square root of 500 k m² = 707.1067812 m).

Finally, the command-line parametrization would be:

```
lastile -i input_file.las -o output_file.laa -tile_size 707
```