# Can my ".las" data be classified

Tags: classification, las

I was given a ".las" data set from a Trimble/AutoCAD shop. I use Esri.

I could not import the .las file they supplied to an ESRI LASDataset as it was created with Trimble software.

I downloaded and used LAStools to convert the Trimble las file to a .txt file parsing "x y z i c r n" columns into the file so i could see what the data set looked like. The coordinates (x y z) are all good, and the intensities (i) look normal, but all of the other data (c r n) is 1's. Everything is a 1.

Can I run classification commands on this data to get ground (bare earth) if all the returns data is 1?

example line from dataset:

1628137.7722 1774278.1248 6821.9085 11308 **1 1 1**

I cannot perform the LAStools "lasground" function yet because I do not have the license to do so and I do not yet have the approval to obtain such a license form my IT guy.  I can go that route eventually.

I just have little experience classifying las data and I want to know, given the above format, will LAStools be able to classify my data into "ground", "noise", etc...?

Here is result of lasinfo command:

[image: Here is result of lasinfo command:]

Comment: Also, look at many other duplicates in https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blidar%5D+%5Bclassification%5D+ground+is%3Aquestion. If it is not duplicate, explain why starting by showing what `lascatalog` from LAStools outputs. .las format is a standard format; it should have worked within ArcGIS. Respond to comments by making edits to the question, instead of replying in comments. Tks.

Comment: I know .las is standard format but when trying to import the file to a LAS dataset in ESRI it would give pop up error of: "One or more invalid or unsupported LAS files were ignored." After using the free LASTool to convert to txt then back to las I was able to bring it into a LASD. However I can't run the paid LAStools yet. Just want to know if based on that format shown above, will LAStools be able to classify my data? I tried MCC but my dataset is too large and needs to be split or tiled (also LAStools that require paid license).

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS are you using? There are improved tools for automated ground classification in 10.5. If you're going to work with LiDAR data in the future I definitely suggest you purchase a LASTools license and experiment with the toolbox and utilities, there's some really good tools there.

Comment: I am using 10.4.1 for Desktop with a Basic license. I am inquiring with RapidLasso about licensing the tools. It sounds like I need them either way, I am just unsure if theyll do the job because I cant try it myself yet.

Comment: Have you tried [Fusion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273486/setting-groundfilter-parameters-for-low-density-point-clouds/277967#277967), [PDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101786/determining-bare-earth-dem-from-unclassified-las-file/261321#261321), [Globbal Mapper](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302912/why-ground-model-from-point-cloud-in-global-mapper-is-inaccurate/303001#303001). [ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188973/classifying-raw-las-data-as-bare-earth-in-arcgis-for-desktop/189458#189458)? The Q was answered 'n' times in GIS SE.

Comment: Andre, I did eventually try Arc with limited success so far. I was not asking how to do it so much as, is the data able to be classified based on what I showed it t look like. Thanks for your suggestions and direction because it did help me get a little further along

Answer (score 0, accepted):

likely not as this is first-return data only.

1. Your data is lacking the standard class info
2. It only contains the first return only.

Note it has no intensity values either.

The nice header tells me this data has been created from a text file and converted into las.

Comment: I do think it has intensity values but you are right everything is first return. I was able to run the Clssify round tool in Arc, idk why I didn't think of that before... Reulsts were so so, very few points ended up being called ground.